# apache pig output null values when loading with int datatype

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am working with pig-0.16.0
I'm trying to join two tab delimited files (.tsv) using pig script. Some of the column fields are of integer type, so I am trying to load them as int. But I see that whichever columns I made 'int' are not loaded with data and they shows as empty. My join was not outputting any result, so I took a step back and found out this problem occurred at the loading step. I am pasting a part of my pig script here:

```
REGISTER /usr/local/pig/lib/piggybank.jar;
-- $0 = streaminputs/forum_node.tsv
-- $1 = streaminputs/forum_users.tsv
u_f_n = LOAD '$file1' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (id: long, title: chararray, tagnames: chararray, author_id: long, body: chararray, node_type: chararray, parent_id: long, abs_parent_id: long, added_at: chararray, score: int, state_string: chararray, last_edited_id: long, last_activity_by_id: long, last_activity_at: chararray, active_revision_id: int, extra:chararray, extra_ref_id: int, extra_count:int, marked: chararray);

LUFN = LIMIT u_f_n 10;

STORE LUFN INTO 'pigout/LN';

u_f_u = LOAD '$file2' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (author_id: long, reputation: chararray, gold: chararray, silver: chararray, bronze: chararray);

LUFUU = LIMIT u_f_u 10;

STORE LUFUU INTO 'pigout/LU';
```

I tried using long, but still the same issue, only chararray seemed to work here. So, what could be the problem?

Snippets from two input .tsv files:

## forum_nodes.tsv:

```
"id"    "title" "tagnames"  "author_id" "body"  "node_type" "parent_id" "abs_parent_id" "added_at"  "score" "state_string"  "last_edited_id"    "last_activity_by_id"   "last_activity_at"  "active_revision_id"    "extra" "extra_ref_id"  "extra_count"   "marked"
"5339"  "Whether pdf of Unit and Homework is available?"    "cs101 pdf" "100000458" ""  "question"  "\N"    "\N"    "2012-02-25 08:09:06.787181+00" "1" ""  "\N"    "100000921" "2012-02-25 08:11:01.623548+00" "6922"  "\N"    "\N"    "204"   "f"
```

## forum_users.tsv:

```
"user_ptr_id"   "reputation"    "gold"  "silver"    "bronze"
"100006402" "18"    "0" "0" "0"
"100022094" "6354"  "4" "12"    "50"
"100018705" "76"    "0" "3" "4"
"100021176" "213"   "0" "1" "5"
"100045508" "505"   "0" "1" "5"
```

Comment: I would suggest [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38421717/edit) your question to add a short portion of the input files, so that other users can try and reproduce the problem (see also [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: looking data shared in question  data is string as it is quoted  ie  "18" is string chararray ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace quotes to let pig know its `int` or else it will display blank. You should use CSVLoader OR CSVExcelStorage, see my tests:

Sample File:

```
"1","test"
```

**Test 1 - Using CSVLoader:**

You can use CSVLoader or CSVExcelStorage if you want to ignore quotes - see [example here](http://www.crackinghadoop.com/hadoop-pig-loading-files-with-quotes-and-comma-delimiters/)

PIG Commands:

```
register '/usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar' ;
define CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();
file1 = load 'file1.txt' using CSVLoader(',') as (f1:int, f2:chararray);
```

output:

```
(1,test)
```

**Test 2 - Replacing double quotes:**

PIG commands:

```
file1 = load 'file1.txt' using PigStorage(',');
data  = foreach file1 generate REPLACE($0,'\\"','') as (f1:int) ,$1 as (f2:chararray);
```

output:

```
(1,"test")
```

**Test 3 - using data as it is:**

PIG commands:

```
file1 = load 'file1.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (f1:int, f2:chararray);
```

Output:

```
(,"test")
```